# If $ x_{n}$ is unbounded sequence then the $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sin(\frac{1}{x_{n}})=0$

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

I tried to say that if $x_{n}$ is unbounded then it is divergent...

Consider the three possible ways for $x_n$ to diverge:

1)$x_{n} \to \infty$.

2)$x_{n} \to -\infty$.

3)$x_{n}$ has multiple limit points.

I thought in either cases (1) or (2), the statement would be true.

In case (3) I took the following sequence:

$x_{n}=\begin {cases}  
n &  n \text{ is even} \\ 
1 &  n \text{ is odd}
\end{cases}$

then $x_{n}$ is unbounded and the statement would be false in this case.

Comment: You are right. Unbounded does not mean convergent to infinity.